# Creating a vector of numbers where no number is within 2 of the previous element

Tags: r

I want to create a vector of numbers which are randomly spaced between 6-20, 21-35 etc all the way to 500. I have done this with sapply

```
positions <- sapply(seq(6, 500, by = 15),function(x) x + sample(1:15, 1))
```

I want to add one more rule to this sequence. I don't want any numbers in this vector to be within 2 of each other, i.e. if my first number is 20 I don't want 21 or 22 for my second number and so on. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: hello, when posing a question with random numbers, it is helpful to set a seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obfuscated code does it - let me see if I can clean it up.

```
positions <- c()
x <- 0
for (i in seq(6, 500, 15))
{
    sub.samples <- setdiff(1:15 + i, seq(x-2,x+2,1))
    x <- sample(sub.samples, 1)
    positions <- c(positions,x)
}
```

Comment: You are right. I dont know why I read as 2 numbers in each interval...I need coffee.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't care about the length of the sequence. If that is the case, and if I understand your question correctly, something like the following should do what you want:

```
positions <- positions[diff(positions) > 2]
```

You may need to use a `while` statement too, in case after removing some values, there are still values within the threshold for removal.

Comment: Perhaps: 
`while(any(dd <- !(diff(positions) > 2))) { positions[dd] <- sapply(starts[dd], function(x) x + sample(1:15, 1)) }`
  where `starts <- seq(6, 500, by = 15)`